# How do i show that : for $x, y >0 ,\log (x+y)=\log{x}\cdot \log{y}$ has no integer solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

I have tried to solve this equation for $x, y >0$, $\log(x+y)=\log{x}\cdot \log{y}$ by writing it as this $x+y={x}^{\log{y}}$. But the last expression is complicated to me to get any solutions, I think it has no solution in integers !!!

**My question here is :** How do I show that for $x, y >0$,  $\log(x+y)=\log{x} \cdot \log{y}$ has no solution in integers?

**Note:** $x, y$ are integer numbers.

**Edit 01:** I edited the question because I have a wrong meaning, I meant in integers.

**Edit 02:** I edited the question to show my key idea for the proof.

**Attempt**: This is just an Idea for the proof

What I think is  : $\log(x+y)\leq\log(xy)=\log{x}+\log{y}$ which is less than $\log{x} \cdot \log{y}$ for $ x, y \geq 8$, hence:
$2\leq \min(x,y)\leq 7$ , which  it's easy to check.

Thank you for any help !!!!

Comment: sorry Daniel i meant in integers not in real numbers , i edited my question now

Comment: RHS  IS  logxlogy

Comment: how it's equivalent to x+y=x.y , i don't write :logx+logy =log(x.y)

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment, that was nonsense...

Comment: ok,no problem Martin

Comment: Prove that $y=10^k$ and $x=10^n$, where $n$ and $k$ are natural numbers.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It's not obvious from the question that $\log$ is assumed to be in base $10$.

Comment: @dxiv $\log$ it's $\log_{10}$ always.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Tell that to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(x)) for example. I agree with you in principle, but reality is that $\log(x)$ is often (mis)used for the natural logarithm.

Comment: @dxiv I think Wolfram is wrong. I agree with you that it's a common mistake. For $\log_{e}$ there is $\ln$.

Comment: I think the assumption that $x,y \geq 8$, in the attempt, indicates natural logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expansion is close to your idea and assuming $\log{y}$ is the natural logarithm.

**Case 1.** Let's assume $x=y$ then $\ln{2y}=\ln^2{y}$. By replacing $\ln{y}=z$ [it's easy to check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-x-ln(2)%3D0) that $P(z)=z^2-z-\ln{2}=0$ has 2 solutions, the largest one $z_2$ **is in between $(1,\frac{7}{4})$** and $\forall z > z_2: P(z)>0$. It's easy to check that $z_2 < \frac{7}{4}$ from $\ln{2} < \frac{21}{16}$.

**Case 2.** Let's assume $x>y$ or [$x=qy+r, 0\leq r<y, q>0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) then 
$$\ln((q+2)y) > \ln((q+1)y+r)=\ln(qy+r)\ln{y} \geq \ln(qy)\ln{y}$$
or
$$\ln(q+2) + \ln{y} > \ln{q}\ln{y} + \ln^2{y}$$
By replacing $\ln{y}=z$ 
$$P(z)=z^2+(\ln{q}-1)z-\ln(q+2)<0$$

**Case 2.a** $q=1$. This means
$$P(z)=z^2-z-\ln{3}<0$$
another [easy to check case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-x-ln(3)%3D0) that the largest solution $z_2$ of $P(z)$ **is in between $(1,\frac{7}{4})$** (from $\ln{3} < \frac{21}{16}$) and $\forall z > z_2: P(z)>0$.

**Case 2.b** $q\geq 2$. We [will check the roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) of $P(z)$
$$D=\sqrt{(\ln{q}-1)^2+4\ln(q+2)}$$
and
$$\sqrt{(\ln{q}-1)^2+4\ln{q}}<D<\sqrt{(\ln(q+2)-1)^2+4\ln(q+2)}$$
([including for $q=2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(ln(4)-1)%5E2%20-%20(ln(2)-1)%5E2)) or
$$\ln{q}+1<D<\ln(q+2)+1$$
And the largest of 2 solution for $P(z)$ is
$$z_2=\frac{-(\ln{n}-1)+D}{2}$$
or
$$1<z_2<\ln{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{q}}}+1<\frac{7}{4}$$
and in fact, with large $q$, is aggressively approaching $1$. In any case, the largest solution $z_2$ **is in between $(1,\frac{7}{4})$** and $\forall z > z_2: P(z)>0$.

**Note:** regarding $$\ln{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{q}}}+1<\frac{7}{4}$$
For $q\geq 2$ we have $\frac{3}{4} > \frac{1}{2} \ln{2} \geq \ln{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{q}}} \Rightarrow \frac{7}{4} > \ln{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{q}}} +1$

In all the cases, we have $\ln{y}=z_2 \in (1,\frac{7}{4})$ or $y \in \{3, 4, 5\}$. The remaining part is to check each $\ln(x+3)=\ln{x}\cdot \ln{3}$, $\ln(x+4)=\ln{x}\cdot \ln{4}$ and $\ln(x+5)=\ln{x}\cdot \ln{5}$ individually, but numerical approaches reveal no integer solutions.